# Add Custom Field in Order and Quote Table To be Used in REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Using UpgradeSchema, I've successfully added two fields to the table

```
quote
```

and

```
sales_order
```

The two fields are called

```
delivery_note_doc_due_date
```

and

```
remarks
```

My question is: how can I add the methods

```
getRemarks()
setRemarks()
getDeliveryNoteDocDueDate()
setDeliveryNoteDocDueDate()
```

inside the

```
Data\CartInterface
```

and

```
Data\OrderInterface
```

modules so that I can use REST API to create an order?

Your help will be much appreciated!

LDR

Comment: You may create extension attribute for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create extension attributes:

etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">    
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="remarks" type="string" />
        <attribute code="delivery_note_doc_due_date" type="string" />       
    </extension_attributes>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface">
        <attribute code="remarks" type="string" />
        <attribute code="delivery_note_doc_due_date" type="string" />       
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```