# How can i add custom values in quote using REST api

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

i have tried this solution [Add Custom Field in Order and Quote Table To be Used in REST API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259963/add-custom-field-in-order-and-quote-table-to-be-used-in-rest-api).
But still the custom field values are not setting in quote table.
Here is my payload for POST request

> <base_url>/rest/V1/carts/mine/items

Payload:

```
{
    "cart_item": {
        "sku": "H6S4K461FDD192",
        "qty": 1,
        "quote_id": "256",
        "product_option": {
            "extension_attributes": {      
                "custom_options":  [
                    {
                        "option_id":"374",
                        "option_value":"1522"
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id":"373",
                        "option_value":"898"
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id":"372",
                        "option_value":"895"
                    }
                ],
                "configurable_item_options": [
                    {
                        "option_id": "93",
                        "option_value": "110"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "extension_attributes": {  
            "layaway":"1",
            "downpayment":"1838.00",
            "finalpayment":"1444.50",
            "duration":"30",
            "bank_name":"Bank Name",
            "layaway_multipay":"0",
            "multi_pay_initial":"0"
        }
    }
}
```

i want to set values of `layaway`,`downpayment` `finalpayment` `duration` `bank_name` `layaway_multipay` `multi_pay_initial` in quote table

i have also added `extension_attributes.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have your custom attributes as columns in the quote table AND also you have a typo in your request :)

As per https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.2-admin/#operation/quoteCartItemRepositoryV1SavePost, the key is 'cartItem', not 'cart_item'

[image]